# Subquery returns more than 1 row PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT mrk_lat,client_id,mrk_lng ,engine_status ,created_date,live_fuel,
(SELECT count(veh_id) FROM we_vehicles) as total_veh,
(SELECT count(veh_status) FROM we_vehicles WHERE veh_status=1) as run_veh,
(SELECT count(veh_status) FROM we_vehicles WHERE veh_status=0) as stop_veh,
(SELECT client_id FROM we_clients)
FROM `we_vehicles_coordinates` WHERE client_id = ".$_SESSION['client_id'];
```

ERROR is :
`Warning: mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Everything is looks good. But when i add the `we_clients` table, It gives me that ERROR.

Thanks

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: That's because (SELECT client_id FROM we_clients) returns more than one row... I will add the WHERE client_id = ".$_SESSION['client_id']; there